# Make [specialabilities] not special

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

This tag has (only) 4 questions and is only recently created (early March).

[specialabilities](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specialabilities) seems useless and should be removed.

Can we burninate this tag?

Comment: Can we just burninate this tag entirely? (I was in the middle of writing the burninate request when this popped up actually)

Comment: It seems appropriate. I can't think of a use of this tag that can't be covered by other tags, like feats, classfeats, etc.

Comment: It seems to be used for 3/4 of the questions for monster abilities. Which I think still falls neatly under [tag:monsters]. That being said, did you want to make this a burninate request officially then?

Comment: @Rubiksmoose done and done

Answer (score 11):

I agree. The tag should be removed. Of the 4 questions it is attached to (one of which is closed), 3 would be better categorized by [monsters](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/monsters) and the fourth apparently tries to apply it to spell effects which falls under [spells](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spells). Additionally it seems like an unnecessary and confusing tag to even have (without really coming up with a narrow definition), after all what *isn't* a special ability in D&D 5e for example?

The tag name is formatted incorrectly as well.

For, all the reasons above, I say let it burn.

Update: Tag has been removed by @ObliviousSage and is no longer special.